# Is it possible in Angular to make my <app-custom-component></app-custom-component> be a html tag?

Tags: angular

I have a list of card which I render in a loop

```
<div class="parent">
       <app-card *ngFor="let item of news" type="news/" [card]="item">
                </app-card>
</div>
```

**card.component.html**

```
<a class="my-class">
....
</a>
```

And when browser render my components I lose some css properties and my view on page is little bit incorrect. My `margins` in `my-class` not working and cards stay close to each other.
I want to make my `<app-card>` be a `<a>` tag and it will effect all css correctly on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the selector or your component is enclosed by `[` and `]` you can use as directive

e.g.

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-card]',
  template: `Hello {{name}}!`
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

use

```
<a app-card [name]="'Angular 10'"></a>
//or
<div class="myClass" app-card [name]="'Angular 10'"></div>
```

Comment: nice thanks , can you please advise where I can read information about such notations `[` `]`

Comment: I can not find in the official docs, but you can take a look to this link about it: https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/when-to-use-an-attribute-selector-for-angular-components-7e788ba1bfe7